# Subsequent click event triggering wrong href?

Tags: jquery-events

I have a script that triggers a "Leaving Site Alert" popup, if the link is an external link that isn't included in a list of allowed domains. The first link clicked always works correctly, but the subsequent links, trigger the popup correctly - but bring users to the first link. Trying to figure out why that's happening.

The jquery (with a little injected hubl) controlling the popup can be found below.

```
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    const popup   = $('.alert-popup-container');
    const domains = [];
    // populate whitelisted domains array - **fyi this is written in hubl**
    {% for item in module.domains %}
      domains.push("{{ item }}");
    {% endfor %}
    
    function confirm (link) {
      popup.addClass('active');

      $('.popup-cancle, .alert-popup-close').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        popup.removeClass('active');
        return true;
      });
      $('.popup-proceed').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(link, "_blank");
        popup.removeClass('active');
        return true;
      });
    }

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
      const target = $(this),
            href   = target.attr("href");

      var trigger_alert = true;

      // make sure url is not relative
      if (href.indexOf('://') !== -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
          if (href.indexOf(domains[i]) != -1) {
            trigger_alert = false; // don't trigger the alert
          }
        }

        if (trigger_alert) {
          e.preventDefault();
          confirm(target.attr("href"));
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Here's the alert popup html:

```
<div class="alert-popup-container">
  <div class="alert-popup">
    <div class="alert-popup-close"></div>
    {{ module.alert_text }}
     <div class='controls'>
       <div class="btn1">
         <a href="#" class='cta_button popup-proceed'>Okay</a>
       </div>
       <div class="btn2">
         <a href="#" class='cta_button popup-cancle'>Cancel</a>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I have a click event inside another click event, which is causing the strange behavior. The issue was fixed by using jQuery's [off()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp) method. What this does is removes the previous click event, assigned when the first button was clicked.

Complete code:

```
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    const popup   = $('.alert-popup-container');
    const domains = [];
    // populate whitelisted domains array - **fyi this is written in hubl**
    {% for item in module.domains %}
      domains.push("{{ item }}");
    {% endfor %}
    
    function confirm (link) {
      popup.addClass('active');

      $('.popup-cancle, .alert-popup-close').off().click(function(e){ // added off() here
        e.preventDefault();
        popup.removeClass('active');
        return true;
      });
      $('.popup-proceed').off().click(function(e){ // and here
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(link, "_blank");
        popup.removeClass('active');
        return true;
      });
    }

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
      const target = $(this),
            href   = target.attr("href");

      var trigger_alert = true;

      // make sure url is not relative
      if (href.indexOf('://') !== -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
          if (href.indexOf(domains[i]) != -1) {
            trigger_alert = false; // don't trigger the alert
          }
        }

        if (trigger_alert) {
          e.preventDefault();
          confirm(target.attr("href"));
        }
      }
    });
  });
```